# Plone, behaviour of URLs

Tags: plone, zope

The situation is the following: I created a site with Plone, developed, used, but behind a test URL. Now it has to be published, but the test URL is not appropriate and I don't want to move the site. I think, if I use a redirect, it won't be appear in the URL-bar, only in the case of site start page. Am I wrong? (The test URL should not be used, because it will be a "semi-official" site.) What do you suggest to do?

As far as I can see Plone uses absolute URLs everywhere. I can add relative URLs, but if I create a new page, a new event, etc., then they have absolute URLs on other automatically generated inner pages. Is there any way to convert these URLs to relative paths? Is there any setting possibilty where only a checkbox changes this default setting?

Comment: Please format your posting properly.

Comment: Sorry. But you cut an important part of it. Why? Optilude's first answer is missing. That's why it is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Plone does not store your URLs in the database. It uses the inbound host header (and any virtual hosting configuration set up with rewrite rules in Apache or Nginx) to calculate the correct absolute URL when rendering the page.

In other words - as soon as you actually point the relevant domain name to the server with your Plone instance, it'll just work.

P.S.
You should put a bit more effort into asking your question. This is just a copy and paste of a half-finished email chain where you tried to get the answer from me in private. It's not very easy to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for copy-paste, but I think, my version was easy to understand. Pynator edited my question and cut your first answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is url rewriting to handle virtual hosting. ie to get your site to appear as if it's the root url of a domain.

This is normally done via the webserver that normally sits in front of plone. For apache, here is a howto
http://plone.org/documentation/kb/plone-apache/virtualhost

for other servers
http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/hosting

You can also achieve this directly in zope (via ZMI) using something called the Virtual Host 
Monster. see http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/VirtualHosting.html

PS. I don't think your question is badly worded. Plone does serve pages with a "base" tag and what appears to be absolute urls. They aren't baked into the database but it's also not obvious that the solution to getting the url you want is the VHM url syntax and a proxying frontend webserver. There is a reason why it doesn't use relative urls... which I can't remember it was so long ago.